# Windows 7 x64 Internet Explorer 8 Speed Problem when using interface

Tags: windows-7, performance

I just reinstalled Windows 7 Ultimate x64 on my laptop as my hard disk was giving me some I/O errors so I wanted to format it and start over.

After the whole intall process was completed I was left with a very slugish IE8, although it used to be very fast on the same configuration before the reintall.

When is it slow?

Everytime a feature is used:

- try to open Tools menu

- when opening a new tab

- entering a new address is slow because it takes time to open the addresses history etc

Basically whenever something from its interface is being accessed it freezes for a few moments then comes back. It' VERY annoying.

Further info:

- I do not want to replace it with another browser, I'm interested in a solution

- I reset its settings from the options menu but to no avail

- I uninstalled then installed IE8 from the Turn Windows Features On or Off menu but to no avail

- I tried running no add-ons version: same.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm seeing something similar, but my symptoms aren't as widespread as yours. I haven't done any re-installations but for the past couple of weeks, IE has been taking a long time to close tabs when I click the `x`. I did some browsing on Microsoft's forums and most of the IE performance questions seem to be a year or more old and apply to Win7 RC. There are newer ones but the common recommendation seems to be that you disable all addons & accelerators, and reset all IE settings to defaults. (Defeats the purpose of running IE8 if you ask me.) The only other mentioned suspect is AVG.

Comment: The IE8 before the reinstall was working perfectly and with the same setup: hardware, add-ons, anti-virus etc.

Comment: What's odd is that it's working perfectly now, without me doing anything. It just showed the customization screen as if it was just installed out of the blue and started working as it should. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

> as my hard disk was giving me some I/O errors

There is your problem. Not in the OS itself.

What almost certainly happened is that your harddisk failed to read some sectors. There things happen. When this happens the drive tries a few times until it succeeds, resulting in delays (this is why your program was slow).

Eventually the drive will either give up (with errors) or internally remap the bad sector. This seems as 'self healing' to the user. YOu probably triggered this by reinstalling windows and writing to that sector.

Next time something is very slow check disk usage for very high busy% but low transfer and read the drives S.M.A.R.T. values.